# Layers not showing

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS and [GPlates](https://www.gplates.org/) to recreate a fictional world with GIS.  Have been tracing a raster map imported into GPlates and using the .dbf files generated as imported layers in QGIS.  All seemed to be working OK.  Now some of the layers have stopped displaying.

I have been playing with the CRS (currently [WGS84 / Mercator 41](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3994)) but all of my layers are set to this, as is the project.  There is now also the problem that my process for bringing in new polygons from GPlates has stopped working.

Comment: I have started with a fresh file in QGIS and importing is working, as is layer display

Comment: What do you mean when you say "playing with the CRS?" I hope you're not changing the CRS of your layers in the layer properties window.

Comment: I see this has been closed but to answer CSK's question, No - all the layers have the same CRS.  I just meant I was trying different ones to see which best displayed the map the way I wanted.

Comment: Your question was closed because you didn't provide enough detail for anyone to solve the issue. If you edit your question to clarify it, it will be reopened. Use the [edit] link under the question. It seems you have two issues. I suggest editing this question down to only one issue (per the "one question per question" rule), and make the other a new question. Issue 1: "Some of the layers have stopped displaying". Issue 2. Your "process for bringing in new polygons from GPlates has stopped working." At a minimum please explain that process for importing polygons from GPlates.

Comment: CSK - no worries - I solved the problem.  Reading many of the online support group threads I can see that I am in quite a way over my head with respect to understanding how the program works.  I will continue to work through the tutorials etc.  I understand the point about asking a question people can understand and answer.  It probably doesn't help that I'm not using the software in a conventional application!